# If two divs are adjacent, I can only affect the last one in CSS using the "+" operator, how can I affect the first?

Tags: css

In my code, I have a structure such as:

```
<div class=block1">
..
</div>
<div class="block2">
</div>
```

These two blocks can be changed at the user's will through a page builder.

Now, it just so happens that block1 **has some special CSS properties on its own that shouldn't exist when it has another special block (block2 in our case) next / before it.**

block1 properties:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 30px;
..
..
```

block2 properties:

```
margin-top: 30px;
border-top: 2px solid;
```

So you can see there are clashing properties and they'd look quite bad. My goal **is to remove the properties from block1 and not block2.** *(I know I can remove from block2, but this is a perfect case where I can remove from block2 to make it work, but it's rarely this easy.)*

Here's a visualisation:

[image: How it should work.]

This code allows me to tell if block2 comes after block1, like this:

```
.block1 + .block2 {
//If block2 is after, do some changes to block2
}
```

I'd want to affect .block1 instead, something like:

```
if(.block1 + .block2) -> .block1 {
    border-bottom: 0; //remove the border bottom so it doesn't look bugged.
    padding-bottom: 0; //cut the paddig since it's not necessary.
}
```

I couldn't find any solution to this except JS, I'm trying to come up with something written in CSS.

Comment: If you need `.block1` special CSS properties to apply if there is only one element of its kind consider using `.block1:only-child {...special styles}`, when there is more than one child of its kind any rules you've declared for the fall-back selectors `.block1 {...default styles}` will apply. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child

Comment: @Paulie_D  What I love about the duplicate is when it is of no help really, solving nothing ... , okay: obviously it says there is no previous selector ... but is there  the 'howto' clearly answered to this case ? ( there is too many alike duplicate to pick up the most relevant :( )

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is :

1. apply same style to every div
2. reset style from the last div you wished to style

example on hover :

```css
div, h1 {
  padding: 0.1em;
  color: blue;
  border: solid;
  margin: 0.25em;
}

article div:hover~div,
.end,
.end  ~div,
h1{/* reset here whate ever you need */
  color: initial/* foo example */
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div><h1>test hovering to see it working.</h1></div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
</article>
<hr/>
<section>
  <div><h1>test via class, same selector involved</h1></div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div class="end">Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
  <div>Do i have any-style ?</div>
</section>
```

CSS has **no "previous sibling selector"**.

Comment: This could work for me, but my structure is `body -> block1 -> block2 -> block3`, I understand these blocks are part of the `body` and are at the same level, but I just can't get this to work.

Comment: what is your actual structure and class names ? blockx are siblings or children ?

Comment: They are siblings, here's a codepen of my exact structure: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPMKBa

Comment: @DanielMoss if one or 2 div , then :only-child would do https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PJdapd What would it be with a third one ?